# VueJS get data before template rendering

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise

I have a vue component which should dispaly and handle filter-options for the results shown on the site.

The code below shows a part of my component. In this example a min and a max price can be set by the user. Because my filter is handled by the backend, I want to get all available filter-option (or the default-filters) before the component is rendered.

Unfortunatelly I get the following error-message: TypeError: Cannot read property 'min' of undefined.

**COMPONENT**

```
<template>
    <div id="filter">
        <fieldset>
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text">Preis von - bis</span>
                </div>

                <select class="form-control" id="min_price" v-model="filter.price.min"
                        v-on:change="countResults">
                    <option value="0" selected="selected">beliebig</option>
                    <option value="250">250 €</option>
                    <option value="500">500 €</option>
                    <option value="750">750 €</option>
                    <option value="1000">1000 €</option>
                    <option value="1500">1500 €</option>
                </select>
                <select class="form-control" id="max_price" v-model="filter.price.max"
                        v-on:change="countResults">
                    <option value="250">250 €</option>
                    <option value="500">500 €</option>
                    <option value="750">750 €</option>
                    <option value="1000">1000 €</option>
                    <option value="1500">1500 €</option>
                    <option value="0" selected="selected">beliebig</option>
                </select>

            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</template>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
    export default {
        name: "VehicleFilterComponent",
        data: function () {
            return {
                categories: [],
                filter: {}
            }
        },
        methods: {
            getDefaultFilter() {
                axios.get(this.$apiUrl + '/vehicles/default-filters')
                    .then(result => {
                        this.filter = result.data.filter;
                    }).catch(function (error) {
                    console.warn(error)
                });
            }
        },
        beforeMount() {
            this.getDefaultFilter();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Is there a way to wait until all filters are loaded?

Right now I make use of `v-if` and set the filter-data per default to false. So the template is only rendered when all filters where loaded.
Is there a better way, maybe via Promises?

Comment: The solution you propose in your question (setting `filter` to `false`) should work, why didn't you try it?

Comment: Just edited the question^^ but thanks for your reply!

Comment: The way you have implemented it is fairly okay but you might run into a few situations, one is, handling when the result from the API is empty. I'll suggest, begin with using a different value to monitor the fetching. Eg: `data.fetched = false`. From there you can render a message telling the user the data has not been fetched and another telling them it has been fetched but had no entries, etc.

Comment: Checkout this example on jsFiddle, it is a similar implementation to my comment: https://jsfiddle.net/adamwathan/xov6ksvd/

Comment: Try to use `beforeRouteEnter: function(to, from, next)` for this.

Answer (score 3):

Your existing solution is not bad. In general, your template rendering should not be linked to data retrieval – consider the case when the server is taking a long time to respond or worse, is completely unavailable for some reason. You should show at least a spinner in this case.

So this means that whatever display logic there is, it should be done "manually" and should not be linked with the Vue lifecycle, i.e. with `v-if` and such.

As for the code itself, you can perhaps make it more clear with `async` / `await` syntax:

```
export default {
    name: "VehicleFilterComponent",
    data: function () {
        return {
            categories: [],
            filter: {}
        }
    },
    methods: {
        async getDefaultFilter() {
            this.filter = (await axios.get(this.$apiUrl + '/vehicles/default-filters')).data.filter;
        }
    },
    beforeMount() {
        this.getDefaultFilter();
    }
}
```